# mysql phpmyadmin - database not showing in mysql cmd pmt 'show databases;' but shows on phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to utilize the database located in the myphpadmin but I'm not sure if I have the capability of accessing the database I need... see the picture below.

I have a connection using user root in mysql and able to see the InformationSchema database when in Terminal (see below). I'm unsure how to access the owldydke_phonebank database... I'm developing a web api and want to access the data. Right now when trying to connect, I see:

```
"Details:  Error: Could not connect to MySQL:
Error: ER_BAD_DB_ERROR: Unknown database 'owldydke_phonebank'"
```

When I connect in my Sails connection.js file, I use database: 'owldydke_phonebank'.

[phpmyadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBdKH.png)

```
Show databases:
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Why is your db showing under "owldydke"? It should be at the level `information_schema` lies.

Comment: @AmitMerchant that's just a grouping by phpmyadmin

Comment: @LizAnderson you either connect to the wrong server or the user cannot see that particular database.